# Efficient/Correct way of accessing a field of a referenced node

Tags: entities, nodes

I have an Article node with a `field_recipe` field which references multiple Recipe nodes which has a field `field_image`.

In the Article node template I have this in my code:

```
$recipes_raw = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_recipe');
```

How do I get the `field_image` from `$recipes_raw`?

Currently, what I'm doing is this:

```
foreach($recipes_raw as $r) {
    $recipe_node = node_load($r['target_id']);
    $field_image_raw = field_get_items('node', $recipe_node, 'field_image');
}
```

However, I'm not very sure if this is an efficient approach since I'm reloading a node which is already part of the current node I'm in.

Comment: I think it is OK cause drupal does not load related nodes , so you must load it by your own if you want to access a field inside a related node.

Comment: Yeah but `$recipes_raw` already contains the nodes that I am reloading using `node_load` so I was thinking it's a bit redundant. If there's was a way to get the `field_image` from `$recipes_raw` directly then It's going to be faster I think.

Comment: All entity loads are statically cached, any delay will be negligible. For a simple improvement, loop through and gather node ids first, then run the lot through node_load_multiple - potentially a lot fewer db queries that way